# Missing Artifact com.google.gwt

Tags: maven, gwt

I try to run an old project with GWT. I got "Missing Artifact" msg. Something is not correctly set up.

Here is the segment of POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.gwtplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-plus-auth</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: A brief [search of central Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.google.gwt.gwtplus) found no such group ID. Perhaps your setup is missing a Maven repository for this library?

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy. Thanks. I found "gwt-oauth2" in com.google.api. How about the other one? Simply updating pom.xml with the correct dependency will work?

Comment: You have to be sure after changing group/artifact IDs that the dependency you switched to is what the project's authors intended to use. Your project might not compile if you switch to an incompatible library.